# Incorrect path of executable file in Linux

Tags: python, centos, wine, centos8

I need to run an **exe** file in Linux which has the Python code:

```
import os
dirname = os.path.normpath(os.getcwd())
print(dirname)
```

When I run the code  with the command `python code.py` , it runs fine

and gives me the output : `\root\path\to\file`.

But when I try to run the exe file with the command `wine64 code.exe` ,

which has the same python code, It gives me the output : `Z:\root\path\to\file`.

I tried to fix it by adding `dirname = dirname.replace('Z:', '')`,

but it doesn't work, How to do this?

Comment: Just changing the `code.py` will not effect the binary file `code.exe`. You will need to recompile the `code.py` which will need a windows machine.

Comment: I had recompiled the file, then transferred it to Linux